# Regex capture groups in []

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract all numbers that look like they may indicate a range in distances using regex in python.

```
s = "3 to 6 km. 3 - 6 km"
re.findall(r'(\d [(to)|\-] \d km)', s)

# desired result ['3 to 6 km', '3 - 6 km']
# result: ['3 - 6 km']
```

How can I modify this to get the desired result?

Comment: Using `\d+ (?:to|-) \d+ km`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can omit the outer capture group and use a single alternation using a non capture group for either `to` or `-`:

```
\d+ (?:to|-) \d+ km
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/89v54A/1)

```
import re

s = "3 to 6 km. 3 - 6 km"
print(re.findall(r'\d+ (?:to|-) \d+ km', s))
```

Output

```
['3 to 6 km', '3 - 6 km']
```